# create a multdimentional array to store many arrays of different sizes in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault

I asked this question but I deleted it because it was not clear. I have three loops which produce 0, 1 data. I would like to store them as a matrix so I think it should be stored in a multidimensional array that I call `Third`.

```
for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < n2; ++l) {
        for (x = 0; x < all[i].n; ++x) {
            f = (int)VECTOR(v2)[l];
            if (a[x].vto == f) {
                printf("%d", 1);
            } else {
                printf("%d", 0);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < n1; ++y) {
        for (x = 0; x < all[i].n; ++x) {
            q = (int)VECTOR(v1)[y];
            if (a[x].vfrom == q) {
                printf("%d", 1);
            } else {
                printf("%d", 0);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");  
}
```

The printed result from the previous code is and I would like to store it on this form:

```
100010001111
111000000111100100010010001001
111000000000111000000000111100100100010010010001001001
110000001100000011101010010101
111100010001
```

My goal is to store the printed result in an array like

`Third = [[[100][010][001][111]] [[111000][000111][100100][010010][001001]]...[[111][100][010][001]]]`

so if I want to access the array `Third` I do `Third[3] = [ [110000] [001100] [000011] [101010] [010101] ]` or `Third[3][1] = [001100]` or `Third[3][1][2] = 1`.

I would be very happy to clarify anything not clear. Thanks for help

**EDIT 1:** The code is too big to be added completely. I asked about the general way to achieve what I am looking for which is how to construct a multidimensional array or an array of arrays to store data results from any three nested loops (not necessary my loops).

I fixed the current code so now the array `Third` contains all the data but I don't think it is the right way to store the data in order to access it later as `Third[3] = [ [110000] [001100] [000011] [101010] [010101] ]`

Here is what I did:

```
    int second[n1 + n2][n1 * n2];
    int first[n1 * n2];
    int Third[m][n1 + n2][n1 * n2];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        Data *a = all[i].datas;
        igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
        igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL);
        igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL);

        int n2 = igraph_vector_size(&v2);
        int n1 = igraph_vector_size(&v1);
        int f, q, x, l, y;

        for (l = 0; l < n2; ++l) {
            for (x = 0; x < all[i].n; ++x) {
                f = (int)VECTOR(v2)[l];
                if (a[x].vto == f) {
                    first[x] = 1;
                } else {
                    first[x] = 0;
                }
                second[l][x] = first[x];
                Third[i][l][x] = second[l][x]; 
                printf("%d", Third[i][l][x]); 
            }
       }

       for (y = 0; y < n1; ++y) {
           for (x = 0; x < all[i].n; ++x) {
               q = (int)VECTOR(v1)[y];
               if (a[x].vfrom == q) {
                   first[x] = 1;
               } else {
                   first[x] = 0;
               }
               second[y+n2][x] = first[x];
               Third[i][y+n2][x] = second[y+n2][x];
               printf("%d", Third[i][y+n2][x]); 
           }
        }
        printf("\n");  
    }
```

when compiling the previous code I get

```
100010001111
111000000111100100010010001001
111000000000111000000000111100100100010010010001001001
110000001100000011101010010101
111100010001
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it? thanks

**EDIT 2:**

I am wondering if the declaration in this way as below is right or not? Is the three dimensional array `Third` of fixed size or it is (as required) dynamic according to `n1` and `n2` which change depending on the iteration of i.

```
    int second[n1 + n2][n1 * n2];
    int first[n1 * n2];
    int Third[m][n1 + n2][n1 * n2];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        Data *a = all[i].datas;
        igraph_edge(&graph, i, &from, &to);
        igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v1, from, IGRAPH_ALL); //initialize the vector v2 where it's values and it's size vary depending on i
        igraph_neighbors(&graph, &v2, to, IGRAPH_ALL); //initialize the vector v2 where it's values and it's size vary depending on i

        int n2 = igraph_vector_size(&v2); // the size changes depending on i, i.e the change from an iteration to another
        int n1 = igraph_vector_size(&v1); // the size changes depending on i, i.e the change from an iteration to another
        int f, q, x, l, y;

        for (l = 0; l < n2; ++l) {
            for (x = 0; x < all[i].n; ++x) {
                f = (int)VECTOR(v2)[l];
                if (a[x].vto == f) {
                    first[x] = 1;
                } else {
                    first[x] = 0;
                }
                second[l][x] = first[x];
                Third[i][l][x] = second[l][x]; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _I would be very happy to clarify anything not clear._ Please, start with a [mcve].

Comment: Also, where does it crash? What did your debugger tell you?

Comment: You should either have a "rectangular" array of arrays capable of holding the biggest array (and have wasted space, but usually not a problem). Or you have han array of pointers to arrays, and then you can define each array separately and store the pointers in the array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: I don't know if the indent broke when you copied the code here, but it would be better if you fixed that.

Comment: It is easy to be off by 1 position when using arrays (C blindly trusts the programmer here) and accessing an array past its bound invokes undefined behaviour (and often causes segfaults). Unfortunately, your code is too far from a [mcve] for others to compile and run it to find what happens. I can only advise you to run the code under a debugger or to add trace prints in order to try to indentify unexpected accesses.

Comment: The best debugging I know for segmentation faults, is to copy this line between any two lines of code where you suspect it could be happening: `printf("%s: %i\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); getchar();`. That way you should quickly find the point where it is breaking.

Comment: @asynts  I've never felt the need of a debugger on a non-embedded program.  That line is usually enough and reading the surrounding code is enough to know the cause, and when you can't see the cause, just add some more `printf`s to read the values of the variables used in the surroundings.  The only reason I've ever used a debugger is when I've programmed a STM32 because obviously I couldn't `printf()`, and sometimes a led was enough/easier than the debugger.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Thanks for your cooperation. I found the error but I am not sure about my procedure to get the array (Third) which I need to call it later as explained in the question

Comment: Please, indent your code properly. If you don't know what that means or how it's done, google it.  I can't read through your code like that.  See your first snippet of code? Somebody fixed it for you. Do something similar with the new code you modified :)

Comment: I updated my answer to include your EDIT2. By the way, what compiler are you using? Don't you have a lot a warnings/errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want this:

```
Third = [ [[100][010][001][111]] [[111000][000111][100100][010010][001001]]...[[111][100][010][001]] ];
```

I will assume from that that the type of data you want is `bool`, but could be any.

This can not be achieved exactly in C, as all the elements of an array have to be of the same type, and that includes its size when we are talking about arrays.

---

Option 1:

But we have for example `*argv[]`, which is an array of pointers, but as pointers can behave like arrays, we effectively have something like this (following your same grammar):

```
*argv[] = [ [program\0][arg1\0][arg2\0] ] // Don't forget the ending NULL, but it's not relevant here.
```

Something similar to what you want could be:

```
void *third[n];
```

And assuming you have all your second arrays defined as

```
bool second_0[4][3];
bool second_1[5][6];
...
bool second_n[4][3];
```

Then you can join them all in `third` like this:

```
third[0] = &second_0;
third[1] = &second_1;
...
third[n] = &second_n;
```

And you could use `third` like this: let's say you want to extract element `[i][j][k]` into a temporary variable, and let's assume that the array `second_i` has sizes `second_i[n][m]`:

```
bool tmp = (*(bool (*)[n][m])third[i])[j][k];
```

The usage is not very nice, but it is the closest thing you can have to what you want.

---

Option 2 (preferred):

You can have a big array like this: `bool third[100][20][30];` which can hold always more numbers than your biggest expected second array has, and just leave as 0 the unused values.  It will use more memory, but it won't need any casts or pointers, and will be a lot faster as all the memory will be contiguous.

If you use this option, you need an extra variable

```
ptrdiff_t third_sizes[ARRAY_SIZE(third)][2];
```

to store the sizes of each second array, so that you can keep track of what portion you have used (with the first option you would need it too).  `ARRAY_SIZE()` should be defined like this:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
```

---

Answer to EDIT 2:

Short: No, dynamic sized arrays do not exist in C. It's not possible.

When you create an array, and use a variable for determining its size, the program just takes the value of that variable at the time of the creation of the array, and that will be the fixed size.  It doesn't update the size when you update the variable.

There are dynamic sized solutions to some problems, such as linked lists (google that if you need more info on it), but not arrays.  Another way to achieve something like an array of dynamic sized arrays would be a mix of the "option 1" above with `malloc()` & `free()`, but I would avoid it as much as I can, because of performance and because of possible bugs.  Some say `malloc()` **is evil**. (Not to not use it, but use it only when there is no alternative).

Still "option 2" above is what I would choose.

Comment: Thanks again. I did something similar to your 2nd option where I declared the three dimensional array Third[m][n1+n2][n1*n2]. m is fixed but n1 and n2 always change depending on the value of m.
I know how to call the value in Third[x][y][z] but I still have a problem how to call the array Third[x] !

Comment: @Noah16  Your array was of fixed width too. Let me show you an example: `n = 3; int m[n]; n = 4;` The size of the array after those statements is still 3.

Comment: @Noah16 To call the array `Third[x]` just write that, `Third[x]`. That's useful for passing arrays to functions (actually pointers to their first element), but remember that you can't assign an array in C. You need to do everything element by element, or use functions such as `memcpy()`.

Comment: I keep comparing c to python and R which I used to work on them. Thanks

Comment: @Noah16 If you still have any trouble after this, update your question with what you have (don't overwrite what you already have, append it).

Comment: Ya I meant to access Third[x] not to call it. I added edit 2 which explain my question. Thanks

Comment: @Noah16 You can not access an array as a whole, you can just call it, but not access it as a whole.